# Errors while adding Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm learning spring MVC from the book in my native language.
It's time for Spring Security. I've copied everything from the book. Unfortunately as a result I got tons of errors. Everything worked before adding it. I think that `security-context.xml` is causing the problem, because links like that on the photo are not used. I'm using IntelliJ.

[image]

Here is my **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**security-conext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/springsecurity-3.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/springcontext-3.2.xsd">
    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/products/add" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/products/add"
                             authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout"/>
    </security:http>
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="Admin" password="Admin123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**login.jsp**

Here I got error with `<form action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"></c:url>" method="post">`. It says that `Cannot resolve controller URL '/j_spring_security_check'`

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Produkty</title>
</head>
<body>
<section>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Produkty</h1>
            <p>Dodaj produkty</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Zaloguj się</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <spring:message code="AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials"/><br/>
                    </div>
                    </c:if>
                    <form action="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_check"></c:url>" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Nazwa użytkownika" name='j_username' type="text">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Hasło" name='j_password' type="password" value="">
                            </div>
                            <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Zaloguj się">
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**LoginController**

```
package com.packt.webstore.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginerror(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "true");
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(Model model) {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Here is stacktrace:
https://pastebin.com/P97E90Ra

I was unable to add here, because it was too long.

Comment: @CrazySabbath https://pastebin.com/uAmeujDK

Comment: @CrazySabbath this link: http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/springcontext-3.2.xsd doesnt work I've got `The requested URL /schema/context/springcontext-3.2.xsd was not found on this server.`

Comment: so update all links and the error you provided is different than the previous one.

Comment: @CrazySabbath well yeah, I had to change link to: http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd but what about  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/springcontext-4.2.xsd It doesn't work. Do I need it? /// EDIT. I put http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd

Comment: Update your security to higher version, as error states: `Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd or spring-security-3.0.xsd or spring-security-3.1.xsd schema or spring-security-3.2.xsd schema or spring-security-4.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 4.2. Please update your schema declarations to the 4.2 schema.` So `spring-security-3.1.xsd` changes to `spring-security-3.1.xsd`. You might one to check your dependencies versions.

Answer (score 0):

The spring security schema URL is incorrect:

- Yours:
  `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/springsecurity-3.1.xsd`
- Correct: `https://www.springframework.org/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd`

If you try to access through the browser the first one (http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/springsecurity-3.1.xsd) you'll get a `404`.

The second one will give you the schema properly  https://www.springframework.org/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd).

---

In general, check all resource URLs you have configured (I don't post them all here since it might be a long list, but it's the same principle)